# Computing $E\left[X\,\middle|\,X \leq \dfrac{Y}{2}\right]$

Tags: conditional-probability

Let X be a uniformly distributed over $[0,2]$, and $Y$ to take values from $[0,\infty]$, how do we compute  $E\left[X\,\middle|\,X \leq \dfrac{Y}{2}\right]$.

My attempt:
$$
E\left[X\,\middle|\, X \leq \dfrac{Y}{2}\right]= \int_0^2 X\,f\left(x\,\middle|\,x \leq \dfrac{y}{2}\right)
$$
I am stuck on how to proceed on from here:
$$
\text{Is }\ \int_0^2 X\,f\left(x\,\middle|\,x \leq \dfrac{y}{2}\right)= \int_0^{y/2} Xf(x)dx\,?
$$

Comment: Is $Y$ fixed? Or is it a random variable? In the latter case, which distribution does it follow?

Comment: Of course not. Surely, you must know what $Y$ is supposed to be.

Comment: edit: Y is non random, but takes value from $0$ to $\infty$

Comment: I think the problem is more interesting if $Y$ is also random and you know the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $Y=y$ is not random there are two cases:

1) $y/2 \geq 2$. Then $y$ does not affect calculations so $$E[X|X\leq y/2]=\int_{0}^2 x f_{X|X\leq y/2}(x)dx=\int_{0}^2 x f(x)dx=1$$

2) $0<y/2 < 2$. Then  $Pr(X < x|X\leq y/2)=\frac{Pr(X < x \cap X\leq y/2)}{Pr(X\leq y/2)}=\min \{2x/y,1\}$ 
so 
$$f_{X|X\leq y/2}(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{cl}2/y & x \in [0,y/2] \\
0 & x \in [y/2,2]
\end{array}\right.$$  Hence,
$$
E[X|X\leq y/2]=\int_{0}^2 x f_{X|X\leq y/2}(x)dx= \int_{0}^{y/2} x/y  dx
= \frac{y}{4}
$$